# how to use angular chrome debug tool to debug across iframe

Tags: angularjs, debugging, iframe

I have an iframe nested in my app that has an angular project in it.

How can I get access to the scope inside that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select iframe from debug options and do something like below:

```
jQuery('#my_element_id').scope();
```

To do this with javascript, I have setup a plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/whVo7wanhmcUfC7Nem9J?p=preview

Below js method access the scope of a element and passes to the parent method:

```
var passScopeToParent = function() {
  var scope = angular.element(jQuery("#myListItem")).scope();
  parent.change(scope);
}
```

parent widnow method accesses scope and changes its expressions:

```
var change = function(scope) {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.department = 'Superhero';
  });
}
```

You can tweak this link to access the scope an element within iframe from parent window and print it in the console window.

Comment: any way to do this with javascript direct?

Comment: jQuery('#my_element_id').scope(); Only if you select the frame.

Comment: Your plunker doesn't actually demonstrate passing scope through an iframe. The javascript that executes gets the scope from its direct parent element (which it can do without `element.scope` via directives). It also doesn't pass it back through the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

The magic is in `<iframe>.contentWindow`

When going from the parent to the child iframe (which is what you do when debugging), you'll want get the child window object, and use its definition of angular.

```
var w = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
w.angular.element(<selector>).scope();
```

Note that this does work with chrome's development shortcuts, so you can do

```
w.angular.element($0).scope()
```

to get the scope of the currently selected element.

EDIT:

You can also directly assign the parent window's angular object to the child's definition (though I wouldn't recommend it if the parent is using angular itself)

```
window.angular = w.angular
```

This makes the parent effectively transparent, so you can use angular as normal

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

and it has the advantage of fixing angular console tools like Batarang

Note: the iframe must be from the same origin in order for this to work. For instance, trying this in plunker won't work as the iframe is generated dynamically, and has a source of "about:blank".

Comment: This gives me a error
`DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://plnkr.co" from accessing a cross-origin frame` on chrome. Any Idea?

Comment: @pravin the iframe contents must be from the same origin. Within the same project, this usually isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party.  What I do is put a button in the directive and attach it to a function that prints the scope.

```
<button ng-click="echoScope()">Echo Scope</button>

$scope.echoScope = function() { console.debug($scope); };
```